# Oneko doesn't last as startup program

Tags: 16.04, startup, cursor, cursor-theme

Oneko, a useless app, I'm trying to make it start on login, (I tried this what they said to do alt-f2... https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html) But once I login, oneko appears, but then disappears after about a second. To install oneko, run terminal and type `sudo apt-get update <br> sudo apt-get install oneko` How do I get it to run the whole session?

Comment: Yes, oneko is the command to start oneko.

Comment: Don't worry, I always do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The cause

In many cases, customizing commands that effect keyboard, mouse and screen need a minor break of appr. 10 seconds after log in. The reason is that obviously local settings in those cases are loaded in a relatively late stage, overruling (or breaking) your commands if they run too early.

#### The solution

Is simple, add a small break to make your command run *after* possible local procedures, breaking your command. In this case, add the following command to start up applications:

```
 /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && oneko"
```

Choose Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add, and add the command above.